# Start a numbered list by keyboard shortcut in an Outlook 2010 Task

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, tasks

I am able to go select via mouse the "Start Numbered List" button. I know there's the keyboard shortcut for a Bullet List which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

But I can't find a keyboard shortcut for the numbered list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any keyboard shortcut for that, but you can simply type "1." (without quotes) and then press space to create a numbered list.

If you want to create a bulleted list, simply type "*" (without quotes too) followed by a space.

Comment: nice! how/where did u pick that up?

Comment: @javadba ahah good question: I don't know :D